# Waveguides: Coplanar Strips vs. Coupled Microstrip line design advantages disadvantages & characteristic impedance (superconducting waveguide)

Tags: electrical-resistance, superconductivity, waveguide

I am very much new to waveguides and I am struggling to calculate the characteristic impedance of my coupled microstrip design. I am using niobium for the electrodes and for the Coplanar Strips I already calculated it (about 80 Ohms Z0), but I am now struggling with the other one. And I am asking myself are there other differences in operating these waveguides, so advantages or disadvantages? I saw in the book where I got the pictures from that the edge coupled one is frequency dependant and has different impedances for even and odd modes, but I don't understand why? Is it also the case for superconductors, when we first build it I thought it would just add capacitance and thus reduce the characteristic impedance Z0=\sqrt((L^K+L^M)/C), where L^K is the kinetic inductance and L^M the magnetic inductance. There is a also calculator https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance-calculator/ that says that it can be used as a filter, why is that?

For the Couples Microstrip line my dimensions are:
s=11.5µm
w=48.5µm
t=70nm
h=70nm
epsilon_r=5/7*9+2/7*4
because it's 50nm Aluminiumoxide and 20nm SiO2.

The pictures are from the Transmission Line Design Handbook by Brian C Wendel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should only ask one question in one post or it will likely be closed. You should avoid homework-like questions and focus on one, for example, starting with why the odd and even modes have different phase velocities, etc.